# Run web server and the selenium server with Gulp + nightwatch.js

Tags: selenium, window, continuous-integration, gulp, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to run some nightwatch.js e2e tests using Gulp.

At the moment I have to do the following:

1. Run the selenium server manually
2. Set the path of `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar` and `phantomjs.exe`
3. Run the web server manually

My gulp task looks as follows:

```
gulp.task("run-e2e-tests", function () {
  return gulp.src('')
    .pipe(nightwatch({
      configFile: "nightwatch.json",
      cliArgs: {
        env: "phantomjs"
      }
    }));
});
```

My nightwatch.js configuration looks as follows:

```
{
  "src_folders" : [
    "bundle/e2e_test/"
  ],
  "output_folder": false,
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "./selenium-binaries/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar"
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : false
      }
    },
    "phantomjs" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : false,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" : "phantomjs.exe"
      }
    },
    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I change `"start_process"` to true I get the following error:

```
[17:10:04] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\CPIC.UI.Web\gulpfile.js
[17:10:04] Starting 'run-e2e-tests'...
[17:10:04] log file
[17:10:04] Starting nightwatch...

[CPIC E2e Test] Test Suite
==========================

Running:  CPIC integration

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)


Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

[17:10:06] 'run-e2e-tests' errored after 1.5 s
[17:10:06] Error in plugin 'gulp-nightwatch'
Message:
    nightwatch exited with code 1
```

The e2e test run as expected but **I would like to run both the web server and the selenium server from Gulp automatically as part of my CI process**.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work! Basically if you install selenium and phantomjs via npm something is wrong so you have to manually download them and set the paths int the nightwatch.js configuration file:

```
{
  "src_folders" : [
    "bundle/e2e_test/"
  ],
  "output_folder": false,
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./selenium-binaries/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar"
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : false
      }
    },
    "phantomjs" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : false,
        "phantomjs.binary.path" : "./selenium-binaries/phantomjs.exe"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To run the web server and kill it I used 3 tasks ans run-sequence:

```
gulp.task("run-e2e-tests", function (cb) {
  runSequence(
    "run-http-server",
    "run-nightwatch",
    "kill-http-server",
    cb);
});

gulp.task("run-nightwatch", function () {
  return gulp.src('')
  .pipe(nightwatch({
    configFile: "nightwatch.json",
    cliArgs: {
      env: "phantomjs"
    }
  }));
});

gulp.task("run-http-server", function () {
  return connect.server({
    port: 8888
  });
});

gulp.task("kill-http-server", function () {
  return connect.serverClose();
});
```